# I cannot disable or reduce docker compose verbose output

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can't find a way to disable the `docker compose` verbose output.

I'm using `docker compose` (version 2) in a pipeline but the output is such long that it's not possible to find any clear error in the pipeline logs. In `docker compose` help I cannot see anything related to `verbose`.

e.g output (I want to disable this kind of output):

`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dockernet.yml up -d`

```
  container1 Pulling                                                      0.5s 

 ⠼ container2 Pulling                                                    0.5s 

 ⠼ container3 Pulling                                                   0.5s 

 ⠼ container4  Pulling                                                  0.5s 

.
.
.
```

I tried `docker compose help` to see if there is any way to disable or reduce the verbosity.

This is an issue as the pipeline job is getting terminated due to such long output:

`The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated.`

Comment: did you try reading `docker-compose up --help`?

Comment: oh, I think `--quiet-pull` will do the trick. Thanks.